# Knockout.js updating form values with json data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am a total newbie with knockout.js and need a very basic understanding of how to simply update my form fields with json data. I have a viewmodel. How do I pull the json data into the observable fields?

```
<p>Errors: <input data-bind="value: errors" /></p>
<p>Message: <input data-bind="value: message" /></p>

// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(myError, myMessage) {
    this.errors = ko.observable(myError);
    this.message = ko.observable(myMessage);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work

$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json", function(data) {

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to set the view model properties explicitly - I feel that is easier to control and maintain.

```
var ViewModel = function(myError, myMessage) {
    var self = this;
    self.errors = ko.observable(myError);
    self.message = ko.observable(myMessage);
    self.property1 = ko.observable();
    self.property2 = ko.observable();
};

var vm = new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth");
ko.applyBindings(vm); // This makes Knockout get to work
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json", function(data) {
    vm.property1(data.field1);
    vm.property2(data.field2);
    ...etc
})
```

If this seems too verbose, there is also the mapping plugin that you can use to automatically map values from JSON into your view model.

Read more about it here:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

```
var vm = new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth");
ko.applyBindings(vm); // This makes Knockout get to work
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json", function(data) {
    var jsObject = ko.fromJSON(data);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(jsObject , viewModel);
})
```

Comment: do you mean that `data` is null, or what, exactly, are you seeing?

Comment: You didn't actually originally state that you need a complete, working example.  At any rate, the JSON URI in your fiddle does not allow requests from jsfiddle.net.  That's why you're not getting any data back.  Check your browser's console output the see the error.

Comment: here's a fiddle that demonstrates more fully:  http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/jMvuD/4/

Comment: Thanks. That gets me on my feet and was what I was looking for.